# input.Substring how to modify each line from textbox

Tags: c#, parsing

I wish to create a 'sanitizing' tool that basically removes excess text that isn't needed from a textbox.

i.e

```
usernamehere:passwordhere | Account creation: X
```

I want to remove any text that comes after it per line

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string input = bunifuCustomTextbox1.Text;

        input = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf("|") - 1);

        bunifuCustomTextbox1.Text = input;

    }
```

The above turns this:

```
usernamehere:passwordhere | Account creation: X
```

Into this:

```
usernamehere:passwordhere
```

---

However, this will remove any other username:password information from the list, and I want it to affect only once per line. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextBox has a Lines property that you can use to access each line of text. You could use a StringBuilder and append each line, then set the TextBox text when finished. Something like:

```c#
var result = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var line in bunituCustomTextbox1.Lines)
{
    result.AppendLine(line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf("|") - 1);
}
bunifuCustomTextbox1.Text = result.ToString();
```

Are you sure every line will contain a | character? It's probably a good idea to check the IndexOf first, so:

```c#
var pipeIndex = line.IndexOf("|");
if (pipeIndex >= 0)
{
    result.AppendLine(line.Substring(0, pipeIndex - 1));
}
```